# MapBox in Dialog shows with additional grey overlay

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I am using MapBox for Android, where the MapBox gets created in the XML layout of  the Dialog. The MapBox loads all well, but it shows a grey overlay when used in Dialogs. I have searched for this problem, and some gave a solution to give another Theme to the Dialog (which worked but resized my whole Dialog to full screen). Another solution seems to be enable textureMode, but I have no idea how I should do that and the documentation really isn't helping me.
Can any of you guys help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is certainly connected to your Dialog Theme, however, to enable `TextureMode` for you Mapbox Map all you have to do is:

```
    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:mapbox_renderTextureMode="true" />
```

enable it in your XML declaration, or:

```
    MapboxMapOptions mapboxMapOptions = new MapboxMapOptions();
    mapboxMapOptions.textureMode(true);
    MapView mapView = new MapView(this, mapboxMapOptions);
```

use `MapboxMapOptions` object if you're are creating the `MapView` programmatically.